# Java jTable MouseListener not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

I have problem with my mouselistener on jTable. 
This is my code:

```
 final JTable jTable1 = new JTable(tablemodel);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(jTable1);

        jTable1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(Event e){
                System.out.println("clicekd on table");
            }
        });
```

But this code not working, When I click on the cell data from the sysout does not show up.
Eclipse tells me: The method `mouseClicked(Event)` from the type new `MouseAdapter(){}` is never used locally

Edit:
This is my function, everything works well except `jTable.addMouseListener`

```
public void categoryShow() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        appListener.getCategory();
        List<Category> people = model.getPeople();

        DefaultTableModel tablemodel;

        tablemodel = new DefaultTableModel();
        final JTable jTable1 = new JTable(tablemodel);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(jTable1);

        jTable1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                System.out.println("clicekd on table");
            }
        });

        tablemodel.addColumn("ID");
        tablemodel.addColumn("Nazwa");

        for (Category person : people) {

            tablemodel.addRow(new Object[]{person.getId(),person.getName()});

        }
        JPanel controls = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,4,4));

        JButton deletebutton  = new JButton("Usuń");
        JButton newrow = new JButton("Dodaj");
        JButton print = new JButton("Drukuj");

        print.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    jTable1.print();
                }catch (PrinterException pe){
                    System.err.println("Blad przy drukowaniu");
                }   
            }           
        }); 
        jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(jTable1.getCellEditor() != null){
                    int col = jTable1.getSelectedColumn();
                    String columnname = jTable1.getColumnName(col); 
                    System.out.println(jTable1.getSelectedColumn());
                    System.out.println("--" + columnname);  
                    System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(),jTable1.getSelectedColumn())); //nowa wartosc
                    System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0)); //id
                }
            }
        });
        newrow.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                final JFrame bankTeller = new JFrame("Dodaj nową kategorie");
                bankTeller.setSize(500, 280);
                bankTeller.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                bankTeller.setResizable(false);
                bankTeller.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                bankTeller.setBackground(Color.gray);
                //bankTeller.getContentPane().add(everything, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

                JPanel acctInfo = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 0;
                c.gridwidth = 2;
                c.gridheight = 1;
                c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
                bankTeller.add(acctInfo, c);
                c.gridwidth = 1;

                JLabel custNameLbl = new JLabel("Nazwa kategorii");
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 0;
                c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
                acctInfo.add(custNameLbl, c);
                c.weightx=1.;

                c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                custNameTxt = new JTextField("",1000);
                c.gridx = 1;
                c.gridy = 0;
                c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
                acctInfo.add(custNameTxt,c);

                closeBtn = new JButton("Anuluj");
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = 3;
                c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
                acctInfo.add(closeBtn,c);

                savingsBtn = new JButton("Dodaj");
                c.gridx = 1;
                c.gridy = 3;
                c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
                acctInfo.add(savingsBtn,c);

                bankTeller.setVisible(true);

               closeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                       bankTeller.dispose();
                   }
               }); 

               savingsBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                       String name = custNameTxt.getText();    
                       if(!name.isEmpty()){
                           fireCategoryEvent(new CreateCategoryEvent(name));
                       }else{
                        //   showMessageDialog(this, "Uzupełnij pole nazwa", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                       }   
                } 
              });
            }
        });
        deletebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int selRow = (Integer) jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0);

                if(selRow >= 0) {
                    System.out.println(selRow);
                }
            }
        });     

        buttons.add(newrow);
        buttons.add(deletebutton);
        buttons.add(print);
        buttons.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Zarządzaj"));

        controls.add(buttons,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        card1.add(scroll);
        card1.add(controls);
    }
```

Comment: That's you're example?  Does you table contain any data? Does the table fill the viewport?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of

```
public void mouseClicked(Event e){
```

should be

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
```

Comment: Eclipse tells me to removed @Override, I my post I show entire function.

Comment: You must be using Java 1.5 which did not allow the annotation on implemented interface methods. Either remove the annotation or upgrade to a newer version of Java

Comment: Where can I check the version of Java for my project and where can I change it?

Comment: Ok. I change Java version in `Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level = 1.7` but I still have problem with `@Override`

Comment: Check the project build path. Is it using a JDK/JRE > 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the files within the Project workspace:

- .project
- .classpath

And the folder:

- .settings

Then I create new projekt with jre8 and import files. My JRE System Library in project = JavaSE-1.7 and everything works well. I must delete unnecessary `@Override` in my function. My MouseListener function looks like @Reimeus told.